# What happens if you run dd without any argument?

Tags: terminal, bash

I was working with Terminal then suddenly I thought of running `dd` without any arguments. Then it started doing something then I immediately started doing something. I got scared so I aborted it using ^C.

Output of `dd`:

```
$ dd
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 2.556354 secs (0 bytes/sec)
$
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, so won't post this as an answer, but I'm pretty sure nothing happens since `dd` on its own has no input or output targets. In fact, I would expect it to just hang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dd` is a "stream duplicator".

Using `dd` with no operands means it will be reading and writing to the standard input/output (keyboard and screen).

From the man page (`man dd`)

> The **dd** utility copies the standard input to the standard output.

So, issuing the command `dd` and then sending a break <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> results in nothing being input, and nothing being written. Until you sent the break, `dd` was waiting for input.

Here are some examples (press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to tell `dd` you are done entering text)

```
$ dd
Hello, World
```

results in

```
$ dd
Hello, World
Hello, World
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
13 bytes transferred in 6.140313 secs (2 bytes/sec)
```

To convert from regular to upper/lowercase:

```
$ dd conv=ucase
Hello, World
HELLO, WORLD

dd conv=lcase
Hello World
hello world
```

Comment: You said, "`dd` is a "stream duplicator".", can you provide an authoritative reference to that statement?

Comment: I put it in quotes because I based it from memory when I first learned it.  I think it had to do with IBM, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Since we're dealing with I/O and that's a stream, I suppose it's okay. +1.